# Using act doesn't update state?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

I have a custom hook like so:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useOpenClose(initial = false) {
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(initial);

    const open = () => { setOpen(true); }
    const close = () => { setOpen(false); }

    return [isOpen, { open, close } ];
}
```

and as for my tests I have something like this:

```
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import useOpenClose from './useOpenClose';

describe('useOpenClose', () => {
    const { result: { current } } = renderHook(() => useOpenClose());
    const [isOpen, { open, close }] = current;

    test('Should have an open function', () => {
        expect(open).toBeInstanceOf(Function)
    });

    test('Should have an open function', () => {
        expect(close).toBeInstanceOf(Function)
    });

    test('Should have initial value of false', () => {
        expect(isOpen).toBe(false);
    });

    test('Should update value to true', () => {
        act(() => open());
        console.log(isOpen)
    })
});
```

Where the test "'Should update value to true'", when I log `isOpen`, it stays false. I'm not exactly sure why it's not updating unless `act` isn't doing what it's doing?

Comment: Try not to use the same hook instance for all the tests bur rather create a new one for each `test`

Comment: For anyone coming here for the answer, it was answered in the `react-hooks-testing-library` repo - https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library/issues/134#issuecomment-517549142

Answer (score 3):

From the doc [Updates](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/basic-hooks#updates):

> **NOTE**: There's a gotcha with updates. `renderHook` mutates the value of `current` when updates happen so **you cannot destructure** its values as the assignment will make a copy locking into the value at that time.

E.g.

`useOpenClose.ts`:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useOpenClose(initial = false) {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(initial);

  const open = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const close = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return [isOpen, { open, close }] as const;
}
```

`useOpenClose.test.ts`:

```
import { act, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import useOpenClose from './useOpenClose';

describe('useOpenClose', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useOpenClose());
    // Don't destructure `result`.
    expect(result.current[1].open).toBeInstanceOf(Function);
    expect(result.current[1].close).toBeInstanceOf(Function);
    expect(result.current[0]).toBe(false);
    act(() => result.current[1].open());
    console.log(result.current[0]);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/57315042/useOpenClose.test.ts (13.635 s)
  useOpenClose
    ✓ should pass (45 ms)

  console.log
    true

      at Object.<anonymous> (examples/57315042/useOpenClose.test.ts:12:13)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |    87.5 |      100 |   66.67 |    87.5 |                   
 useOpenClose.ts |    87.5 |      100 |   66.67 |    87.5 | 10                
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.588 s
```